# I have a problem with outputting 2 values from a single drop down

Tags: javascript, php, dropdown, selector

Im trying to modify a calculator PHP which is based on drop down selections

I have 5 Drop downs. One of which when the value is selected it outputs either "18" or "72" based on what is selected.  Within that table is another column which has the values "1" "0.5" "0.4" "0" how do I get the drop down to select both rows to help me get them into a string for calculation?

This is the input / selector (this is where i need to add the extra row based on what the user selects in the drop down)

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($bunkernic)) { 
    echo '<option value="'.$row['nic_mg'].'"'.($_POST['nic'] == $row['nic_mg'] ? " selected": "").'>'.$row['select_nic'].'</option>'; 
}

?>
```

Currently that outputs the `nic_mg` to a `$input` which changes when a user selects (i can see this when i use `print_r ($input);`)

Could anyone guide me to achieve this? 
If you need any more info / or files to take a look at let me know

I may not be making any sense here, I'm a complete beginner at this but I feel I'm picking little bits up

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put both column values into the `value` attribute, with a delimiter between them.

```
    $val = $row['nic_mg'].'|'.$row['other_column'];
    echo '<option value="'.$val.'"'.($_POST['nic'] == $val ? " selected": "").'>'.$row['select_nic'].'</option>';
```

Then when the form is submitted, you can split the value:

```
list($nic_mg, $other) = explode('|', $_POST['nic']);
```

Comment: First off, Thanks for your swift reply.
Ok so i now have `<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($bunkernic)) { 
echo '<option value="'.$val.'"'.($_POST['nic'] == $val ? " selected": "").'>'.$row['select_nic'].'</option>';
}
      
?>`

I cannot work out where the $cal bit goes and also there is no submit, it auto calculates `onchange="calculate()` I think it is

Comment: If you're doing the calculation in JavaScript you can use the `split()` function to split the value into an array with the two values.

Comment: I'm, unsure how to do that also, but yes it has js in the file.  Would it be part of the `function calculate`   as that is where i can see the reference to `document.getElementById`

Comment: `let [nic_mg, other] = document.getElementById("thisid").value.split('|');`

Comment: This is the current js code i see `function calculate() {
 var inputstring = document.getElementById("shot").value + ";" 
 + document.getElementById("size").value + ";" 
 + document.getElementById("BB_nicotine").value + ";" 
 + document.getElementById("ratio").value + ";" 
 + document.getElementById("nicotine").value;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {`

Comment: I have added it below the funciton `+ document.getElementById("nicotine").value;
 let [nic_mg, nic_mg_percent] = document.getElementById("thisid").value.split('|');
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {` and the results diappeared on the page

Comment: `thisid` should be `nicotine` That was just a placeholder because I didn't know your actual ID.

Comment: ok i have added that into there,  its placed just before the `if` statement,   there still is no output showing either

Comment: After checking again it has worked so now I can see the `$input` has the split value `|` now in the other file its referenced by doing `$nic = ($input)[4];` how do i pull each value to add to my calculation.

Comment: That's what I showed above. You use the variables `nic_mg` and `nic_mg_percent` in your calculations.